# Why can't the images in the animation be displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just cloned a project at https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu, and I added the CircleMenuLib folder to my project. When I run my project, the animation effect can be displayed normally, but the images on the animation can't be displayed. I have tried re-cloning the complete code, but it's still the same.

I'm sure that all the codes and images are completely cloned.

Can someone please explain this, or at least tell me what I need to write to get it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have two projects:

1. Cloned repo
2. Your own project

You added CircleMenuLib to your project, but have you copied images from the Assets.xcassets folder of the cloned repo to your current Assets folder?

Comment: I have copied all images to my current Assets folder, but these images cannot be displayed and they are shown in full red.

Comment: You need do drag and drop them into Xcode navigation area, and in Copy-Wizard check value "Copy items if needed" [link](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/copy-items-if-needed.jpg)